# Prove that if $B$ is the set of rationals in $[0,1]$ with a finite subcover, then: $1 \leq \sum_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following homework problem:

Let $B$ be the set of rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, and let $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be a finite collection of open intervals that covers $B$. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n m^*(I_k) \geq 1$.

---

This is my approach, First we have that $B = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Now, $B \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$, where $I_k$ are open intervals.In particular $0 \in B \wedge 1 \in B$.Now, since $B \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$ then there exist positive numbers, $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1$ such that:
$$(0-\epsilon_0,0+\epsilon_0)\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$$
$$(1-\epsilon_0,1+\epsilon_0)\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k.$$

Clearly, $-e_0 \notin [0,1]$ and $e_1 \notin [0,1]$.I am not sure, if so far I am in the right track.

Comment: Your proof is still wrong. You didn't even use that the $I_k$ are intervals, but this assumption is crucial!

Comment: You just write "this implies", but this is in no way a trivial implication. Also, you still didn't use the interval property in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your argumentation.

There are open covers of the rationals in $[0, 1]$ that don't cover the whole interval. For example, let $x_i$ be an enumeration of all those rationals and take the sets of the form $(x_i - 2^{-i - 10}, x_i + 2^{-i - 10})$. The subadditivity of the outer measure shows that these sets don't cover the whole interval $[0, 1]$.

Note that $[0, 1]$ isn't even always covered by the $I_k$. Consider the open intervals $\left(-1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\right)$.

However, there are at most finitely many numbers that aren't covered by the union of the intervals. More precisely: Show that there are at most $n - 1$ numbers that aren't covered by the union of the $I_k$. Conclude that there are real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ so that each of the intervals $(x_i, x_{i + 1})$ is a subset of the union.

Comment: I am not quite understanding your hint. Correct me if i'm wrong. I can define $B = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ and clearly $B \subset [0,1]$. Now, since $\cup_{k=1}^n I_k$ is an open cover for $B$, I need to show that $[0,1]$ can also be covered by finite cover of $B = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$? I am not understanding the set $s$ at all.

Comment: You need to show that a finite cover of $B$ with open intervals already covers $[0, 1]$. $s$ is not a set, but a real number. I've changed the notation a bit, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: I modified my approach, but still not sure if its correct.

Comment: No, it's still wrong. You talk too loosely about the density of the rationals. Also note that the introduction of the open cover is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I modified my approach again, but I am still not understanding when to use the hint. It is not enough to show that if the interval $[0,1]$ is contained in an open cover of $B$, then using the monotone property and the finite sub-additive property gives the desired result.

Comment: My hint was actually wrong, as the intervals don't always need to cover $[0, 1]$. I've given a new hint.

Comment: I think I got the problem, I'm going to update it as soon as I can.

Comment: @RicardoCervantes, if you could provide a solution to this problem, that would be great. I'm currently working on it and am having a bit of trouble.

Comment: @JessyCat I already have the solution, I will post it as soon as I can.

Comment: @RicardoCervantes, thank you. I posted this question a few minutes ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477462/prove-sum-of-the-lengths-of-intervals-in-a-finite-covering-of-mathbbq-cap-0

If you want, you can post the solution there, and then I can accept it and you can get points.

Comment: @JessyCat I already posted the solution, hope it helps

Comment: @RicardoCervantes, it does. I'm going to go work through it now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 12):

Another  way to tackle this problem is the following :
 Let $ \left \{ I_{k} \right \}_{k=1}^{n} $ such that $ \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subseteq \bigcup^{n}_{k=1} {I_{k}} $

Taking closures implies that $ [0,1] \subseteq \bigcup^{n}_{k=1} \overline{I_{k}} $ Thus $ 1 \leq m(\bigcup^{n}_{k=1} \overline{I_{k}}) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}m(\overline{I_{k}})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}m({I_{k}}) $

$ \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n}m({I_{k}}) \geq 1 $ which is exactly what we wanted to prove .